# How to calculate the presence time of student during a class session with image processing

Tags: python, database, image-processing, logic

I am trying to calculate the total presence time of students using face recognition. Such that at the end of class i can get two things: 1, total time a student was present. 2, from which time to which time he was present, and same for when he was not present(i.e. 9:00-9:20(Present), 9:20-9:22(not present), 9:22-9:42(present))

This is the way I am doing it.

In a 40 min class a python file runs after every 2 mins for 40 seconds.

Each time the file runs it stores the ids of students that are present, in a list data structure and stores it in the DB. I made totaClassTime/2 columns in table as the file runs after every 2 mins. By the end of the class(after 40 mins) it read the data from DB and calculates the total presence time and save it too in DB.

Is there a better way to do this all such that I don't have to create classTime/2 columns in table? Another ambiguity arising:

if for a student we get this data from DB:

```
9:00  9:02  9:04  9:06  9:18  9:10  9:12  9:14  9:16...  
  p    p     -      p     -    p      p    p      p ...
```

when calculating the total presence time it will add time from 9:00 to 9:02 then it will consider 9:02-9:04 as absence time and same for 9:04-9:06. however the student might be present b/w 9:04-9:06. I have searched alot but couldn't find the way to calculate the presence time accurately.

Answer (score 0):

You could store each observation in a row instead of a column. Such a table looks like this:

```
 classId | studentId | observationTime | present
----------------------------------------------------
     1           1           9:00            p
     1           1           9:02            p
     1           1           9:04            -
     1           1           9:06            p
     1           1           9:08            -
     1           1           9:10            p
                       ...
```

Then to evaluate a student's presence time all rows containing observations of this student in the particular class can be selected and ordered by time. This can be achieved with a select statement similar to this one:

```
SELECT observationTime, present FROM observations WHERE classID='1' AND studentID='1' ORDER BY observationTime
```

Now, you can simply iterate of over the result set and of this query calculate the presence times as you did before.

Your problem with the student having an unclear presence state between  9:04-9:06 can be solved by defining for which time frame for which your observation is considered to be valid.

You have already split your class into two minute frames (from 9:00 to 9:02, from 09:02 to 09:04 and so on). Now, you can say that the 9:00 observation is valid for the time frame from 09:00 to 09:02, the 09:02 observation is valid from the timeslot from 09:02 to 09:04 and so on. This enables you to clearly interpret the data from your example: the 09:04 observation is valid for the time from 09:04 to 09:06. As the student was not observed at 09:04 he is considered to be absent in this slot. At the next observation at 09:06 he is present, so we consider him being the class from 09:06 to 09:08.

Obviously the student was not really away the full time between 09:04 and 09:06 unless he magically materialized in his seat exactly at 09:06. But as we only look at the class every to minutes we can only account for the student's presence at a two-minute resolution.

You are basically taking a sample of the state of the class at point in time every two minutes and assume it represents the state of the class at the whole two minutes.

Comment: Glad, that I could help. Can you mark the anser as accept so that it is clear that your problem has been solved? Thanks